# Build tool and project configuration. How to?

Tags: c#, msbuild

Good day experts!

I am about to start a new project and I would like to have a build script for my code. It will be a .NET project developed with VS2010.

Unfortunatelly, I have no idea how to start. What should the build script do? What are the best practices? How should I configure the projects/solutions?

Is there a how to guide for this? I was thinking about using msbuild.

Thanks

Comment: Start - Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt - cd /ProjectDirectory/ - msbuild /projectname/.sln - is a good start.

Comment: Here is a nice [getting started blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/25/the-visual-studio-blog.aspx) with sample code. MSBuild can be tricky, good luck...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big your product will be I would suggest using a Version Control System like TFS and when having that in place you could/should also use a build engine like TeamBuild. May look like overkill but my bet is that it is even easier than trying to figure out how MSBuild works...

Answer (score 0):

Some good practices:

Aim for a "one click build" approach. Try to put all your projects for an app under a single solution. That way, you can build the whole stuff with a single command. Plus, with projects like SharePoint ones, you can create all packages during build (this requires customizing the .csproj files, but it's worthy), I have to try it but this may work

```
<PostBuildEventDependsOn>
  $(PostBuildEventDependsOn);
  CreatePackage;
</PostBuildEventDependsOn>
```

This also helps you in searching across "Entire Solution", so all devs can be in sync without ambiguities.

Make sure to have some good naming convention. For ex. a solution like MyApp containing projects like MyApp.Model, MyApp.View and MyApp.Presenter if you are following an MVP pattern, etc.

Which brings us to another point: aim for a layered organization of your code. A project for utilities, another for your business model, another for presenters, yet another for your UI, etc. That facilitates testing, reusability, etc.

Either case, [just try](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/quantity-always-trumps-quality.html) with different approaches and evaluate by yourself pros and cons.